# How to get the url from the application inside a thymeleaf processor?

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

In my current spring project, I created a custom thymeleaf processor. The implementation for this processor needs to retrieve the url for the application, liek the value returned for `${pageContext.request.contextPath}`  in jsp pages. Someone knows how to get that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Inside view:**

In Thymeleaf, the equivalent of JSP's `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` would be `@{ }`, ie. if you have a url in jsp like `${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login` then in thymeleaf it would be `@{/login}`. The /*[[ - ]]*/ syntax is used by Thymeleaf to evaluate variables in javascript, like `var url = /*[[@{/login}]]*/;`

Ref: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html

**Inside Processor Class:**

First you need to cast context to IWebContext and then get HttpServletRequest object calling getRequest and finally you will get context path by calling request.getContextPath(). You may want to check if context is a type of IWebContext using instanceof operator, I have skipped that here.

```
    final HttpServletRequest request = ((IWebContext) context).getRequest();
    System.out.println("contextpath: " + request.getContextPath());
```

Comment: Ok, but that is what I already use in my views. I want retrieve this information in the java class for my custom processor.

Comment: Sorry about my misunderstanding. answer updated, check now. :-)